# How do I access a value stored in an array reference of hash references?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, reference

I'm working with the [Samba::Smbstatus](https://metacpan.org/pod/Samba::Smbstatus) module for Perl. The documentation says that values are returned in an array reference of hash references. How would I go about accessing values?

I've tried a few methods and gotten nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
use Data::Dumper;

for my $hash_reference (@$aray_reference) {

  # to check what keys are available
  # print Dumper $hash_reference; 

  print $hash_reference->{attr1}, $hash_reference->{attr2};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) and print the results. This may helps you to access the information you are looking for in the result you get.

Imagine your structure is something like:

```
my $data = [ {one=>1, two=>2}, {three=>3, four=>4} ];
# Access three key this way:
print $data->[1]->{three}, "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're talking about the return from the `services` method?

This is one way to access all the data in the structure.

First, the `$services` array reference is dereferenced with `@$services`, and you can then iterate over it with a `for` loop like any other array.

Each element `$service` is a hash reference. If you look again at the documentation, you will see that it has keys `service`, `pid`, `machine`, and `connected`. To access a hash element using a reference, you write `$hashref->{key}`. So I have added four `printf` statements to print the values of those four elements.

I haven't been able to test this, but the syntax checks out.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Samba::Smbstatus;

my $smbstats = Samba::Smbstatus->new;

my $services = $smbstats->services;

for my $service (@$services) {
  printf "Service:   %s\n", $service->{service};
  printf "PID:       %s\n", $service->{pid};
  printf "Machine:   %s\n", $service->{machine};
  printf "Connected: %s\n", $service->{connected};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if $arrayRef is what you get, here is what you need to do to get to all the values

```
for my $hashRef (@$arrayRef) {
    foreach my $key (keys %$hashRef) {
       print $hashRef->{$key}, "\n";
    }
}
```